# how to use nested components in angular 17 with standalone components?

Tags: angular, nested, components, angular17

Since angular now has stanalone components, how do we show one comonent inside another like we used to. e.g  inside app body

I dont have any idea about how standalone components work and i'm a fresher in angular just migrated from angular 12 to angular 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have misunderstood, but nothing has really changed in respect of child components.  The only difference is the parent component will need to import the child component reference in the `imports` array:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'parent',
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    ... <child></child>
  `,
})
```

I found this guide to the standalone API very useful: [Getting started with standalone components](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components).